# default packer root user password

Tags: packer, infrastructure

```
{
  "type": "amazon-ebs",
  "instance_type": "t2.micro",
  ....
  ....
  "ssh_username": "packer"
}
```

I am might be missing something I think,
What is the default packer root user password if not set on build ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. Most Amazon AMI's uses *cloud-init* to retrieve a public ssh key that it will allow the *default user* to login with, this user will have password less sudo rights. The default user for Amazon Linux is `ec2-user` and for Ubuntu it's `ubuntu`.

If you only specify `ssh_username` in your packer template Packer will create a temporary keypair that it will use during provisioning.

You should probably read the AWS EC2 docs, especially [AWS User Guide - EC2 Key Pairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)